# Azure AD B2C without redirecting to b2clogin url

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am planning to use React app and login in my app with Azure AD B2C. Is it possible to avoid redirect to b2clogin url and just login via my application UI. I know about opportunity to customize the login page in b2clogin url, but I really need to avoid using this domain and implement login UI in my application?

Answer (score 0):

While not usually recommended to do so, you could use the [ROPC Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow) to implement UI within your own code.

Do note the limitations mentioned in the doc. Here are the same for reference

> When using the ROPC flow, consider the following:
>
> - ROPC doesn’t work when there's any interruption to the authentication flow that needs user interaction. For example, when a password has expired or needs to be changed, [multifactor authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/multi-factor-authentication) is required, or when more information needs to be collected during sign-in (for example, user consent).
> - ROPC supports local accounts only. Users can’t sign in with [federated identity providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-identity-provider) like Microsoft, Google+, Twitter, AD-FS, or Facebook.
> - [Session Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior), including [keep me signed-in (KMSI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior#enable-keep-me-signed-in-kmsi), isn't applicable.